# Lwc with ApexChart.js

Tags: lightning-web-components

Does anyone know an example of how to use apexchart.js library in LWC, or how to make a Stacked Bar
[image]

[ApexChart](https://apexcharts.com/javascript-chart-demos/bar-charts/stacked-100/)

HTML file

```
<template>
  <div class="c-container">
     <div data-id="apexchart" lwc:dom="manual"></div>
  </div>
</template>
```

JS File

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import ApexChartsLib from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/ApexCharts';
import { loadScript } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';

export default class TestCmp extends LightningElement {

chart;
renderedCallback(){
      
    var options = {
        series: [{
        name: 'Marine Sprite',
        data: [44, 55, 41, 37, 22, 43, 21]
      }, {
        name: 'Striking Calf',
        data: [53, 32, 33, 52, 13, 43, 32]
      }, {
        name: 'Tank Picture',
        data: [12, 17, 11, 9, 15, 11, 20]
      }, {
        name: 'Bucket Slope',
        data: [9, 7, 5, 8, 6, 9, 4]
      }, {
        name: 'Reborn Kid',
        data: [25, 12, 19, 32, 25, 24, 10]
      }],
        chart: {
        type: 'bar',
        height: 350,
        stacked: true,
        stackType: '100%'
      },
      plotOptions: {
        bar: {
          horizontal: true,
        },
      },
      stroke: {
        width: 1,
        colors: ['#fff']
      },
      title: {
        text: '100% Stacked Bar'
      },
      xaxis: {
        categories: [2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014],
      },
      tooltip: {
        y: {
          formatter: function (val) {
            return val + "K"
          }
        }
      },
      fill: {
        opacity: 1
      
      },
      legend: {
        position: 'top',
        horizontalAlign: 'left',
        offsetX: 40
      }
      };

    Promise.all([
        loadScript(this, ApexChartsLib)
    ]).then(() => {
        console.log('LIBRARY: ' + ApexChartsLib);
        const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        const chartNode = this.template.querySelector('[data-id="apexchart"]');
        chartNode.innerHTML = "";
        chartNode.appendChild(canvas);
        const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        this.chart = new window.ApexCharts(ctx, options);
        this.chart.render();
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log('ERROR: ' + error.message);
    });
}
```

}

Comment: Have you tried to utilize one of the numerous tutorials regarding Chart.js, e.g. [this](https://medium.com/@ishaarora_49656/add-dynamic-data-to-chart-in-lwc-9d88e8b4516e) and apply it to ApexChart?

Comment: Yes, I've tried it, but it doesn't work

Comment: ApexChart.js has a render function that doesn't work -> var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), options);
        chart.render();

Comment: It would be helpful to [edit] what you've tried, code you may have attempted, and any specific issues/errors you've encountered.

Comment: Okay, I put the code I'm using above

Comment: Are you only loading a Javascript file? Does this work without CSS?

Comment: I don't know if it works without the css file, I'm just loading the apexchart.js file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unzip apexcharts-bundle.zip and you find a reference to ResizeObserver (line 30664 of apexchart.js). This is not supported by the [Locker API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/locker-service-viewer). You can make this work by replacing Locker by the brand new "Lightning Web Security" however, which is in Beta:

Setup - Security - Session Settings - Lightning Web Security (Beta)

Assuming you have markup like this:

```html
<template>
    <lightning-card title="ApexChart.js" icon-name="custom:custom1">
        <div class="chart slds-var-m-around_medium" lwc:dom="manual"></div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

And assuming you uploaded the zip file:

```js
import { loadScript } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
import apexchartJs from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/apexchartJs';
```

In the renderedCallback you do:

```js
loadScript(this, apexchartJs + '/dist/apexcharts.js')
.then(() => {
        const div = this.template.querySelector('.chart');
        const chart = new ApexCharts(div, this.options);
        chart.render();
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Failed: ' + error);
    });
```

This will render you the Stacked Bars chart.

Comment: Thank you very much! I actually had to enable 'Lightning Web Security' and I had just uploaded the js file, but the correct thing is to upload the whole zip, thanks again, it made all the difference.